# Evento sobre dom desde innerHTML

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

Tengo una lista `li` cargado con `innerHTML`, el cual quiero darle una clase a cada uno con el evento `onmouseenter`.

Esto me funciona bien pero con el evento del teclado, pero no asi con el evento  `mouseenter`.

Este es mi uso del evento `mouseenter` que no me funciona (ni con mouseover):

```
userOpcionAll.forEach( (e) => {

e.addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => { 
    let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = ev.target;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
});
```

});

```js
const userSelect = document.getElementById("userSelect");
const userOpciones = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");
const userOpcionAll = userOpciones.querySelectorAll(".opcion");

function cargaOptionsUser() { // Carga de option en form user

  const opcUserPais = [{
    pais: "Argentina",
    codigo: "+54",
    value: "0000 000 000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/ar.png"
  }, {
    pais: "Bolivia",
    codigo: "+591",
    value: "0 000 0000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{8})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/bo.png"
  }, , {
    pais: "Brasil",
    codigo: "+55",
    value: "00 00000 0000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{11})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/br.png"
  }, {
    pais: "Chile",
    codigo: "+56",
    value: "0 0000 0000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{9})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/cl.png"
  }, {
    pais: "Paraguay",
    codigo: "+595",
    value: "000 000 000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/py.png"
  }, {
    pais: "Uruguay",
    codigo: "+598",
    value: "0 000 0000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{8})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/uy.png"
  }, ];

  let opciones = [];

  opcUserPais.forEach((item) => {
    opciones += `
            <li class="opcion" value="${item.value}" data-txt="${item.pais}">
                <img src="${item.bandera}"> <span>${item.pais}:</span> (${item.codigo})
            </li>
        `;
  });

  userOpciones.innerHTML += opciones;
};

function usuarioSelect() {

  userOpciones.classList.toggle("activo");

  if (userOpciones.classList.contains("activo")) {

    userOpciones.addEventListener("mouseleave", yoDesseleccion);

  } else yoDesseleccion();

  function yoDesseleccion() {
    userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
  };

};

userOpcionAll.forEach((e) => {

  e.addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => {
    let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = ev.target;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
  });

});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  cargaOptionsUser(); // Cargar etiqueta option en formulario User
});

userSelect.addEventListener("click", usuarioSelect);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

let activo = userOpciones.classList.contains("activo");
let active = userOpciones.querySelector("ul li.activo");
  
if(e.key == "ArrowUp" && activo) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = active.previousElementSibling || active.parentNode.lastElementChild;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");

} else if(e.key == "ArrowDown" && activo) {

    e.preventDefault();
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = active.nextElementSibling || active.parentNode.firstElementChild
    active.classList.toggle("activo");

} // else if(e.key == "Enter" && activo) yoSelectCódigo();
});
```

```css
:root {
  --textoPeque: .80em;
  --azul: rgb(13 110 253);
  --gris: rgb(128 128 128);
  --negro: rgb(0 0 0);
  --blanco: rgb(255 255 255);
  --fondoGris: rgba(128 128 128 / 0.5);
  --fondoVerde: rgba(16 88 55 / 0.5);
  --gris-20rem: 0 0 0 .20rem var(--fondoGris);
  --azul-5: 0 0 .25rem var(--azul);
  --transicionNormal: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  --blur2: 2px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: var(--transicionNormal)
}

.btn-gris {
  color: var(--negro);
  border-color: var(--gris);
  background-color: var(--gris)
}

.btn-gris:hover {
  color: var(--negro);
  box-shadow: var(--gris-20rem);
  background-color: var(--gris)
}

.userSelect .userSelect-opciones {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 185px;
  max-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: var(--radius-10-rem);
  overflow-y: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: var(--fondoGris);
  backdrop-filter: blur(var(--blur2));
  transition: var(--transicionNormal)
}

.userSelect .userSelect-opciones.activo {
  max-height: 300px;
  pointer-events: all
}

.userSelect .userSelect-selecto {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.userSelect .userSelect-selecto span {
  display: none
}

.userSelect-opciones .opcion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .30rem .30rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: var(--textoPeque);
  color: var(--blanco);
  text-shadow: var(--azul-5)
}

.userSelect .userSelect-selecto img,
.userSelect-opciones .opcion img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo {
  color: var(--enlace);
  background-color: var(--fondoVerde)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="userSelect" class="btn btn-sm btn-gris userSelect"> 
                                            <div id="userSelect-selecto" class="userSelect-selecto">
                                                Seleccionar
                                            </div>
                                            <ul id="userSelect-opciones" class="userSelect-opciones">
                                                <li class="opcion activo">Seleccionar</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando defines:

```
  const userOpcionAll = userOpciones.querySelectorAll(".opcion");
```

Aun no se han cargado los `<li>` que agregas con la funcion *cargaOptionsUser()*, ese selector solo tomara los que ya tengas definido en el documento HTML.

Mueve tanto la definición del selector como el forEach que agrega el evento *'mouseenter'* a cada `<li>`, al evento 'DomContentLoaded':

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  cargaOptionsUser(); // Cargar etiqueta option en formulario User
  const userOpcionAll = userOpciones.querySelectorAll(".opcion");
  userOpcionAll.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => {
    let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = ev.target;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    });
  });
});
```